# How does cross_val_score, cross_val_predict, and cross_val_validate take care of training, testing and validation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

As per my understanding, `cross_val_score, cross_val_predict, and cross_val_validate` can use `K-fold validation`. This means that the training set is iteratively used in part as a training set and test set. However, I have not come across any information on how Validation is taken care of. It appears that the data is not divided into three sets- training, validation and test sets. How does cross_val_score, cross_val_predict, and cross_val_validate take care of training, validation and testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross_val_score is used to estimate model's accuracy in a more robust way than with just the typical train-test split. It does the same job, but repeating it many times. This "repetitions" can be done in many different ways: CV, repeated CV, LOO, etc. See 3.1.2 in [sklearn User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation)

In case you need to crossvalidate hyperparameters, then you should run a nested cross validation, with one outer loop to estimate model's accuracy and one inner loop to get the best parameters. This inner CV loop will split the train set of the outer loop further in train and validation sets. The procedure should go something like:

```
Outer loop:
    Split train - test
    Inner loop:
       Fix parameters      
       Split train in train2 - validation
       Train with train2 set
       Score with validation set
       Repeat Inner loop for all parameters
   Train with train set and best parameters from inner loop
   Score with test 
   Repeat outer loop until CV ends
   Return test scores
```

Fortunately, sklearn alllows to nest a GridSearchCV inside a cross_val_score.

```
validation = GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid)
score = cross_val_score(validation, X, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`cross_val_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) does take care of validation in so far as the process splits the dataset into `K` parts (3 by default), and performs fitting and validation `K` times. [Sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) talks about *splitting the dataset into train/test set*, but do not misunderstand the name. That test set is in fact a validation set.

By using `cross_val_score` you can tune model hyperparameters and get the best configuration.

Therefore, the general procedure should be to divide (by yourself) the dataset into a training set and a test set.

Use the training set for cross-validation (invoking `cross_val_score`), in order to tune model hyperparameters and get the best configuration.

Then use the test set to evaluate the model. Note that the test set should be large *enough* and representative of the population in order to get an unbiased estimate of the generalization error.

Comment: Although it is largely a matter of terminology, arguably the cross-validation does take care of validation, but not of testing - after all, it is called cross-*validation*, not cross-testing...

Comment: I agree with @desertnaut here. I would like to know why in your opinion cross_val_score does not take care of validation... That operation of splitting the dataset in K folds precisely corresponds to what is referred to as "validation" in ML.

Comment: It is a matter of terminology, indeed. How does sklearn name the products of the splitting process in KFold? Train/test sets. How do we name the phase in which we tune model parameters and assess its ability to generalize to an independent set? Validation. How do we name the phase in which we assess the performance of a fully-specified model? Testing. So, in a sense you both are definitely right. `cross_val_score` does cross-validation, where each of the `K` test sets is in fact a validation set used to validate the model. I am going to edit my answer to be unambiguous. Thanks.